# Adding a column to a downloaded xlsx file

Tags: r, download, xlsx

I want to download a xlsx file for each row of a column of my data .For this I wrote:

```
    library(RCurl)
    u = read.table("Mydata.txt" , header = TRUE)

    res = list()
    for(i in 1:nrow(u) ){
      # For each row it goes to this url and download it's file
     MyURL<-"URL"
     # The Name of the file 
      dir = paste(u$V1[i], "_",i , ".xlsx" , sep="")
      # Downloading the file 
      tables <-download.file(MyURL, destfile= dir , mode="wb") 
#Reading the downloaded file
  excel.file<-read.xlsx(dir,1)
      # Counting the list 
      print(i)
          Sys.sleep(0.05)
}
```

The problem is that I want to add a column to the downloaded file that the value of this column in all cells of that should be the value that I have download it's file means `u$V1[i]` and then save it.For this after downloading I read it but I don't know what can I do to add such column in this file?

Comment: You need to break down your problem into small parts since its not clear what the problem is. Do you know how to read an XLSX file into an R data frame? Is that at least part of the problem?

Comment: Yes I edited and added reading the downloaded file @Spacedman

Comment: It's still not clear what you'd like to accomplish. It would be helpful to show (conceptually, preferably with examples) what you would like to do, specifying which part you have a problem in. To answer, people would probably need to know the structure of **Mydata.txt** and the downloaded files you talk about.

Comment: The question is that "How can i add a column with a speific value to a xlsx file in R?" @pbahr

Comment: I would read the xlsx file into a dataframe, add the needed column to the dataframe (probably involving some calculations on the other columns), and write it back to the original file.  @minoo I was trying to get a sense of what your code is trying to do in order to help. A reproducible example is always helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much @pbahr ,you really helped me alot.